Flutter Xcode Build takes forever after upgrade
After I upgrade my MacOS to 14.6.1 and Flutter to Channel stable, 3.24.0, I am stuck with building xcode forever… Compiling, linking and signing... but never completes...
Anyone experiencing this?

It happens sometimes due to invalid caches or builds presents in your system.
Here is how I resolved it.
Delete this folder to remove all temporary or cache

~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/

After that open Settings/Storage and you will see storage of Developer kindly remove Cache if present check screenshot below.
After that kindly restart your Mac and it will be resolved.

